# How to specify multicast group for Crate cluster

Tags: multicast, crate

I'm currently trying to make a cluster of N nodes on n computer. But (I'm not a network expert), in my office network, multicast is only allowed on specific multicasr groups and port.

I didn't find in crate config how to specify group ip, Hazelcast can do this.

Any idea ? Multicast is so much cool than unicast.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As Crate uses Elasticsearch for discovery (and for lot of other things), configuring a multicast group is done the same way as in Elasticsearch.

Add following to your `crate.yml`:

`discovery.zen.ping.multicast.group: <YOUR_GROUP>`

See also https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html#multicast

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at MulticastConfig.

```
Config config = new Config();
config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getMulticastConfig()
            .setMulticastGroup(multicastGroup)
            .setMulticastPort(multicastPort);    
HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
```

Comment: not sure what this answer is for, question is about crate, not hazelcast.